# Extract tomcat parameters from ps output

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, ps

I'm trying to write a little diagnostic tool and one of the functions I want from it is that I want to run is:

```
ps axu | grep tomcat | grep -v grep | awk '{ print $<list of desired fields> }'
```

I want to return the userid that started tomcat and the following parameters that were passed when tomcat started:

```
-javaagent:/usr/share/tomcat7/<someagent> -Dcatalina.base=/var/lib/tomcat7 
- Dcatalina.home=/usr/share/tomcat7 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/tomcat7-tomcat7-tmp
```

I want those fields passed into an array which I can then use to tell the user something about the tomcat install.

The problem is I can't find a way of formatting the command to force the fields to be what I need them to be to make awk work.

At this point I'm thinking of just taking the output, writing it to a temp file, then pulling what I want out using regex.

I know there's a way to do this in Bash but I have not had any success getting there from here.

Comment: It needs to be from ps output?

Comment: I should clarify something. This is a tech support tool that will be provided to customers and so I can't know in advance what form of *NIX they'll be running ahead of time.  It occurred to me that there's another way to get at it. Since this is meant to be used by other IT people I thought I could just build a menu and just ask them for their OS which I could then pass the appropriate ps command for.  If that is a worse idea than the one before, let me know. I appreciate the feedback y'all have given me so far.  It's been invaluable.

Comment: @AdrienneDavis Don't ask the user to do something that can easily be done automatically! You can detect the OS automatically — but you don't need to, you can just stick to standard features (as I do in my answer).

Answer (score 3):

Pass the `-o` option to `ps` to control which fields it outputs. If you add an `=` sign after all the fields, then the header line is omitted.

Use `-e` instead of `ax` to stick to [standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/ps.html) features (this will work on any non-antique unix).

Your filter with `grep` is not robust. For example, if you run this command from a script called `look-for-tomcat`, then your script would be matched as well. Here's a more robust way that looks for a JVM process with `org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap` as an argument.

```
ps -e -o user=,args= | awk '
    $2 ~ /java$/ &&  / org\.apache\.catalina\.startup\.Bootstrap($| ) {
        print "user name: ", $1;
        if (match($0, / -javaagent:[^ ]* /)) print substr($0, RSTART+1, RSTART+RLENGTH-2);
        # etc.
    }'
```

Even better would be to log the PID of the tomcat process in a file (e.g. `/var/run/tomcat.pid`) when it starts.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `/proc` on your particular flavor of *nix, you may try to coax the data you want out of that instead. I think this may be a bit saner than attempting to wade through the tedium of parsing output that is meant for a human to read.

For example, to get the user ID that started the `tomcat` process, you can do:

```
stat -c'%u' /proc/$(pgrep tomcat)/
```

Relying on the availability (and standardization) of `/proc` may be even more of a hassle depending on your particular application/environment/... It's up to you to decide, I guess.